# Why does wget give me two different total download times?

Tags: bash, time, download, wget

The last 3 lines of `wget -i urls.txt`:

```
FINISHED --2012-05-16 12:58:08--
Total wall clock time: 1h 56m 52s
Downloaded: 1069 files, 746M in 1h 52m 49s (113 KB/s)
```

There are two different times:

```
1h 56m 52s
1h 52m 49s
```

Why are they different? What do they stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have wall clock time and a shorter time, the shorter time is usually user time and the missing time system time (time spend in the kernel) or time waiting for something like a file descriptor. (But I have not checked what's the case with wget). If you are curious start `time wget http://some.url` or look into `/proc/<wget-pid>/stat` while it's running (assuming you are running on linux).

Answer (score 3):

Wall clock time or real time is the human perception of passage of time. That will be the time as a human user, what we will experience. In this case wget might have took less than the real time to finish its job, but the real time is the sum of time the software took to finish its real job and the time it was waiting for resources like hard disk, network etc.